# Add sass loader to the webpack already using react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have this configuration in my webpack and I need to add sass-loader, 
I already added the dependencies using 
`npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev`

But I'm confused where I include the sass loader and the documentation settings.
Now how to add to my webpack?

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const validate = require('webpack-validator')

module.exports = validate({
    devtool: 'source-map',

    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index'), 
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],

    module: {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: /src/,
            loader: 'standard'
        }],
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: /src/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }],

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add `sass-loader` in order to support scss files.
Add a new item to the loaders/rules array:

If you use webpack < v3:

```
loaders:[
  ..., 

  {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
  }
]
```

For webpack > v3 add a rule like this:

```
rules:[
..., 
   {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
    }
]
```

For more details look here https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/